# Show unauthenticated while cloning git repo

Tags: git

Tried cloning a repo, which i can not mention here. show error as unauthenticated.
any help would appricated

code i am using is

```
git clone gitrepourl
```

any help would appriciated

Comment: If it is repository in your organization ask administrator about credentials

Comment: can you paste your gotcloneurl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure about your condition but i can suggest a few options,

1. You can authenticate via ssh if your server allows that
2. can try to update your password via windows credential manager
3. else you can try add remote https://email:passs@domain.com/reponame and hit command again

Comment: `git add remote https://email:passs@domain.com/reponame` works fine